# xscreensaver not locking second screen, sometimes

Tags: xscreensaver

Using xscreensaver on Mint 18.3 with xfce4 does not always work with two displays. I have bound it to a keyboard shortcut which runs xflock4, which in turn does run

```
xscreensaver-command --lock
```

Many time this works fine, but more often than not it runs the selected safer application on one screen only. The other screen is left as is. While it is not possible to type something in, so at least the keyboard is locked, it is not nice that the screen contents are still visible.

Interestingly, when I use the display setting gui to apply a minor change, like minimally change the relative position of the screens, xscreensaver afterwards works as expected.

Any ideas where to look for?

Just in case, here is the xrandr output active while it does not work.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 2212, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1200+0+1012 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95* 
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected 2560x1600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
   2560x1600     59.97*+
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and contacted the xscreensaver developer for assistance. He replied suggesting that I try running verbose logging.

```
$ killall xscreensaver    
$ /usr/bin/xscreensaver -verbose -log xscreensaver.log
```

I then set up the screensaver to blank after 1 minute and lock after 0 minutes (immediately on blank).

Tailing the logs in another terminal with the command `tail -f xscreensaver.log` allowed me to view the logs in real time.

I found the following error:

```
xscreensaver: 09:13:46: WARNING: RANDR and Xinerama report different
xscreensaver: 09:13:46:                 screen layouts!  Believing RANDR.
```

This lead me to test and conclude that the problem only occurs when the screens are overlapping. The issue is not yet fixed, but for me the workaround was to ensure that there is no overlap in the screens.